# Passing parameters to Echo route middleware

Tags: go, middleware, go-echo

How to pass a parameter to middleware in Echo? There is an example of what I want to achieve.

```golang
func (h *handlers) Check(pm string, next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        if pm == "test" {
            return next(c)
        }
        return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusUnauthorized, "")
    }
}
```

And I want to set the middleware like this:

```
route.Use(middleware.Check("test input"))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a closure to give your parameter to the middleware, like this:

```golang
func (h *handlers) Check(adminName string) echo.MiddlewareFunc {
    return func(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c echo.Context) error {
            if c.QueryParam("username") == adminName {
                return next(c)
            }
            return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusUnauthorized, "")
        }
    }
}
```

Here the middleware checks whether the query parameter `username` matches the middleware parameter `adminName`. With this example, anyone can get admin status if they know the right username, so no security. You may want to use the BasicAuth or JWT middleware instead, they are already available for `echo`. Have a look at `echo/middleware/basic_auth.go` for a better example.

And you can set the middleware as in your question:

```golang
route.Use(middleware.Check("admin"))
```

Comment: I've used the parameter in the same way as in your question, but obvious there would not be much value in using such a middleware.

Comment: I want this middleware for checking user access level by passing the needed role as a parameter to the middleware, what's your approach to doing that? @clément

Comment: My answer applies if you want to set a parameter to the middleware. I think what you're trying to do is getting a parameter from the query instead, which you can get from the context. You can combine both, I've edited my answer to illustrate.

Comment: No, I want to get a parameter from middleware function. I want to have a one middleware for all different ACL check, something like adminRoute.Use(Check(admin)) and userRoute.Use(Check(user)). @clément

Comment: Right, I see. Well, the code in the answer works for that.